# $(window).scroll function is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using a $(window).scroll event triggered function on my website, all is well only that it doesn't work on mobile devices.

This is the code I am using:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wh =  $(window).height();
    var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if( scrolledFromtop > wh ){

        $('html').addClass('scrolled');
    }else{
        $('html').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
```

I also tried this code but with no success:

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove",aaa, false);
function aaa(){
    var wh =  $(window).height();
    var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if( scrolledFromtop > (wh) ){           
    $('html').addClass('scrolled');
    }

    else {
        $('html').removeClass('scrolled');
    }

};
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: I tried on android based systems with chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

Some(?) mobile browsers simply do not fire the event until scrolling has completely stopped.

You can try few things to solve this problem:

1. use setInterval
2. use Touch Events
3. Another solution out there is to disable native scrolling altogether and use JavaScript to mimic scrolling instead.

`$('window').on('touchmove', function(event) {
    //Prevent the window from being scrolled.
    event.preventDefault();`

```
   //Do something like call window.scrollTo to mimic the scrolling
   //request the user made.
});
```

You can found much more about this, in this great article:

http://tjvantoll.com/2012/08/19/onscroll-event-issues-on-mobile-browsers/